# Word for cheap manufactured art

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

There's a word for cheap manufactured art but I can't remember it and it's almost impossible to search for a word like that.  Does anyone know what it is off the top of their head?

Comment: Could it be a *knockoff*?

Comment: Or *kitsch*? Any hints, like how long it was or what letter it started with?

Comment: @RegDwight: I usually understand *kitsch* as pre-war cheap mass-produced "art-deco". Post-war we had *pop-art*, and nowadays I suppose it's *bling*.

Comment: I'd like to use it to describe these worthless junk art images that keep getting shared on fb

Comment: like 'platitude plastered chintzy kitsch images'

Comment: [Crudely painted, not-so-funny plywood cutout folk art!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j9EOjizFxFA)

Comment: If you wanted a metaphorical term, you could use _Velvet Elvis_.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velvet_Elvis) mentions that Velvet Elvis paintings are considered "an archetypical example of kitsch."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Kitsch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kitsch)** might just possibly be the word.

Answer (score 2):

*Tat* is the word I use, though imprecisely.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was [***tchotchke***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tchotchke) (or tshotshke, tshatshke, tchachke, tchotchka, tchatchka, chachke, tsotchke, chotski, or chochke) depending on where you're from.

A friend of ours has a small store called Chatskies (yet another spelling) where she sells exactly what you're talking about, cheaply made artsy souvenirs and other oddities.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what we're encapsulating as part of the question but if for example we refer to small wearable art such as bracelets and necklaces and the like, or small knick-knacks, the word ***[trinket](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/trinket)*** comes to mind:

> **trinket**
>   *noun*
>   A small ornament or item of jewellery that is of little value.