# Is there a term like "doggerel" is for verse, but general to art?

Tags: terminology

> doggerel ˈdɒɡ(ə)r(ə)l/ noun
>
> verse or words that are badly written or expressed.

Its most famous poet is [Mcgonagall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_McGonagall)

> Beautiful Railway Bridge of the Silv'ry Tay!
>
> Alas! I am very sorry to
>   say
>
> That ninety lives have been taken away
>
> On the last Sabbath day of
>   1879,
>
> Which will be remember'd for a very long time.

Is there a term for similarly bad or totally ineffective expressions which is general to any art?

Comment: I don't know, but this is a fantastic rabbit hole I fell down trying to find out http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Bad_Art

Comment: For *paintings*, the equivalent is ***daubings***.

Comment: good comments, thanks. obvs 'vulgar' or 'kitsch' don't cover it

Comment: Related: [A word for cheap manufactured art?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/67505/8019).

Comment: Your title mentions 'doggerel' which is not necessarily bad or ineffective (it is not particularly serious though). Are you looking for a term for bad art or doggerel-like art ([which would be art that follows rhyme and meter rules very loosely in a humorous fashion](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/doggerel) )

Comment: @Mitch i don't find that sorta misreading *helpful*, even if not deliberate; i did define the sense i was using.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'misreading'. Did I misread the title word 'doggerel', it's dictionary definition, or your statement 'bad or ineffectual? Which of those three, or other, is your primary intent?

Comment: Or rather, where did you get that definition of 'doggerel', 'badly written'? I can't find a link for it?

Comment: @Mitch google, google definitions. you seem like you want to fight about the definition of a term i used, i find that boring to the point of inanity

Comment: also e.g. (1st link i clicked that isn't open edit) oxford dictionary "1.1Verse or words that are badly written or expressed". everyone else seems to have understood, so maybe move to chat if you like

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42179/discussion-between-user3293056-and-mitch).

Comment: @user3293056 I didn't mean to strike a nerve (as it seems I've done anyway). My canonical idea of doggerel, which may differ from the rest of English speakers, was of irregular rhyme/meter, which happens to match the first definition (not the second) given by [Google: "comic verse composed in irregular rhythm."](https://www.google.com/search?q=definition+doggeral&oq=definition+doggeral&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4181j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) followed by "verse or words that are badly written or expressed.".

Comment: The broadest idiomatic term might be _low-brow art_. It covers Elvis-on-velvet paintings, bodice-ripper romance fiction, reality TV, tabloid supermarket-counter weeklies, crappy arena-band music—basically anything in the world of entertainment that combines schlock, vulgarity, and a naked materialistic appeal to lowest-common-denominator esthetics.

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
Word or phrase requests are out of scope, unless they are expert-level, particularly interesting, unique, and thought-provoking, and show effort and research.
For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Comment: @MετάEd well that's pretty arbitrary whether you define it as interesting. what did you want me to research, exactly ?

Comment: Not arbitrary, but I agree it is subjective. Expert-level is subjective too, but I'd say the question needs to show results of research before it can even begin to be considered expert-level. Results of research means making a thorough search for an answer before asking the question, and including the results of your search in the question, as well as stating why it didn't help. Quoting from "How to Ask": "This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!"

Answer (score 1):

While it can be applied to things other than the arts, the term *[dreck](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/dreck)* is often used

> (informal) 
>   Rubbish; trash:
>   *this so-called art is pure dreck*

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Also derived from Yiddish, the term *[schlock](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=schlock)* is found, and can similarly refer to other goods or activities

> Something, such as merchandise or literature, that is inferior or poorly made.

*American Heritage*

Comment: as with "schlock horror" ?

Comment: @user3293056 It's schlock until it becomes a cult classic.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest **amateurish**.

> [am·a·teur·ish](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/amateurish) (ăm′ə-tûr′ĭsh, -cho͝or′-, -tyo͝or′-): adj. characteristic of an amateur; not professional.

Some exemplar sentences:

> - The art critics find his paintings amateurish.
> - Very few of Mendelssohn's early compositions could be called amateurish.
> - His sculptures are, at best, totally amateurish.
> - His dance moves, which are painfully amateurish, are hard to watch.
> - Bonnie's amateurish soprano voice is suited best for choral groups, not for soloing.
> - I would characterize Jason's acting skills as obviously amateurish.

Despite the word *amateurish* having its etymological roots in one of the Latin words for love [French, from Latin *amātor*, lover, from amāre, to love.], a person's love of participating in an art form does not necessarily give birth to art which could be described as professional, accomplished, mature, seasoned, skillful, exquisite, sublime, nuanced, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The term parallel to 'doggerel' in the sense you intend, but "general to art", would be an adjective rather than a noun, modifying the noun applied to the particular art form ('music', 'painting', 'sculpture', etc.).

> **inaesthetic**, *adj.*
>   Not æsthetic; void of æsthetic perception or taste.

["inaesthetic, adj.". OED Online. June 2016. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/93049?redirectedFrom=inaesthetic (accessed July 08, 2016).]

Alternatively, and perhaps more precisely but less frequently used,

> **unaesthetic** (ˌʌniːsˈθɛtɪk) *adj*
>   1. not beautiful
>   2. not in good taste

(Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged, 12th Edition 2014. S.v. "unaesthetic." Retrieved July 8 2016 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unaesthetic )

The true aim of all art is esthetic quality (beauty), and insofar as art is effective or good it achieves that aim. "Bad" or "ineffective" art may aim for other goals--inculcation of morality, entertainment, promotion of right knowledge, etc.--or may simply miss the esthetic goal entirely due to the ineptitude of the artist.

This answer, however, sets aside a common understanding of 'doggerel' in favor of the sense you intend. 'Doggerel' is not universally understood to be "ineffective". Quite the contrary, 'doggerel' is often defined as *effective* in achieving particular goals (inaesthetic in themselves, but perhaps subordinated to an overall esthetic goal proper to art) *by reason of its crudity*:

> **doggerel**
>   loosely styled and irregular in measure *especially for burlesque or comic effect*; also :  marked by triviality or inferiority.

([*Merriam-Webster*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/doggerel), emphasis mine)

> Doggerel, a low, or trivial, form of verse, loosely constructed and often irregular, but *effective because of its simple mnemonic rhyme and loping metre. It appears in most literatures and societies as a useful form for comedy and satire*. It is characteristic of children’s game rhymes from ancient times to the present and of most nursery rhymes.

([*Encyclopædia Britannica*](https://www.britannica.com/art/doggerel), emphasis mine)